# Hide jquery datepicker and show native in mobile

Tags: jquery-ui, mobile, datepicker, native, desktop

I'm using datepicker from jquery-ui.
My input is `type=text`. I want to show datepicker only when I'm on desktop, but when I'm in mobile browser I want to show the native datepicker.
If I put `type=date` and i activate datepicker, it is showed together with the native datepicker, obviously.

How can I do to show jquery-datepicker in desktop and native in mobile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not directly check if a device is a mobile phone or a desktop. However, you could check if the current browser has a native datepicker.

Use [modernizer](https://modernizr.com/) to check if the target browser has a native datepicker. Then, only if it does not have a native datepicker use the jQuery UI datepicker. You can achieve it like this:

```
<label>Date <input type="date"></label>

<script>
if(!Modernizr.inputtypes.date){
     $(’input[type=date]’).datepicker({
         // Consistent format 
         dateFormat: ’yy-mm-dd’
     });
}
</script>
```

If a browser has a native datepicker, then the format is always YYYY-MM-DD (see [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)), therefore one should set the format of jQuery UI datepicker also to `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I also recommend to take a look at this [article](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/30/creating-a-native-html5-datepicker-with-a-fallback-to-jquery-ui/).

Note that you could also check with Modernizr if the target device is a touch device with `!Modernizr.touch`. However this is not useful, since there exists touch devices without native datepicker (Realistic scenario: Desktop computer with touch screen using firefox) .

Comment: above: `data` should be `date`

Comment: you missed the data in `!Modernizr.inputtypes.data` ;)

Comment: @daslicious thank you! I am sure one day this post will be correct :P

Comment: @Adam that day came!